# Save Local Notification in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, uilocalnotification

How to save the local notification? I want to use the local notification fire date again to schedule local notification.

Comment: Not understand what you want. Post some code or elaborate more.

Comment: why do you what to fire the notification again in the same date? your question is very hard to understand.

Comment: My purpose is to use same firedate but change repeatinterval or action on specific day.

Comment: To  Hugues BR : Your answer not exactly what I want... But I have use another way to solve my own problem. I still appreciate for your helping!

Answer (score 0):

You should use `UILocalNotification`

Please check out documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/

It look something like:

```
UILocalNotification *localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
localNotification.fireDate = dateTime;
localNotification.alertBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Alert Fired at %@", dateTime];
localNotification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
localNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
```

About notification re-schedule cycle:

Firing the notification is not enough to show up another one. Your app won't be launch except if user tap the notification.
You could pre-schedule a notification for every day or week for the next month and unschedule them if user open one. Depending of your need you could also fire a `remote notification` with a `content-available` key which will launch your app in background and allow you to reschedule a new local notification.